# Kotlin fold error "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied"

Tags: kotlin, fold

I get an error for this fold function;

```
fun <T> addAll(num: List<T>) : T = num.fold(0, {x,y -> x+y})
```

saying:

**None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.**

However if I do:

```
 fun addAll(num: List<Int>) : Int = num.fold(0, {x,y -> x+y})
```

It works without problems.
Is it possible to keep the function generic in order to use it for lists of both integers and doubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Kotlin does not currently allow abstracting over all number types's operators (I believe that's to be able to use primitive numbers in the JVM runtime).

So the best you can get is something like this:

```
fun <T> addAll(num: List<T>, zero: T, adder: (T, T) -> T) : T =
        num.fold(zero, adder)

println(addAll(listOf(1,2,3), 0, Int::plus))
println(addAll(listOf(1.0,2.0,3.0), 0.0, Double::plus))
```

Comment: Couldn’t you call fold directly then?

Comment: Well, this is close enough. Thanks.

Comment: exactly :) But I think this is possible with Arrow (functional lib). I will add another answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

While you unfortunately can't do it with a single generic functions, you could simply use `sum` which is defined for many [`Iterable`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterable/) types like `Iterable<Int>` and also `Iterable<Double>`:

```
val doublesSum = listOf(1.0, 2.0).sum()
val intsSum = listOf(1, 2).sum()
```

This would at least solve the current problem :)

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of sum but I am currently attempting to learn how to work with generic functions.

Comment: Ok I see, then it’s not very useful I guess

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use functional programming.
Only do this if you're familiar with FP and need very very generic solutions.

Here's an example using the [Arrow](http://arrow-kt.io/) library:

```
import arrow.core.identity
import arrow.data.ListKW
import arrow.data.foldable
import arrow.data.k
import arrow.typeclasses.monoid

inline fun <reified T> addAll(num: List<T>): T =
        ListKW.foldable().foldMap(monoid(), num.k(), ::identity)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(addAll(listOf(1, 2, 3)))
    println(addAll(listOf(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)))
    println(addAll(listOf("one", "two", "three")))
}
```

Comment: Notice that this only works for `addAll` because the monoid for int uses `plus` as its combining operation... not sure why Arrow does that, given that `subtract` or `multiply` would also form monoids if I understand it correctly...